# How refresh Href in svg periodically

Tags: javascript, svg

I've made a SVG with javascript for navigation as shown in http://www.carto.net/svg/navigationTools/

My map SVG is made with 2 externals references and one of these references must be refreshed periodically.

```
(use xlink:href="France.svg#france") and (use xlink:href="routs.svg#routes" id="carout" )
```

Once I refresh the page, my zoom is back to 1:1. Instead I would like my page to refresh the reference and reload the page with the active zoom selected.

Comment: Can you show some code that illustrates your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, it seems like you simply want to refresh the second HREF periodically. The problem is that the browser won't reload it unless the HREF address attribute itself changes. So one solution might be to append the date/time to the end of the address - as described in this stackoverflow answer: [Refresh image with a new one at the same url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/).