# ajax reload linked image

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, firefox

```
function display_hist()
{   
    document.getElementById("display_area").innerHTML=''; 
    document.getElementById("display_area").innerHTML='<img id="hist" src="hist.jpg" width=480 height=480>';


}
```

I have an ajax function that tries to reload an image with the same URL when called by some other code. However, I keep getting the cached image. How can I force the browser to reload the image? Or how to turn off cache functions in firefox COMPLETELY(who thinks he is so smart by caching the content, I have enough! I DON'T WANT ANY CACHE!!) , that is fine as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url

Comment: Not quite, that post uses codes like var newImage = new Image();
newImage.src = "http://localhost/image.jpg";

Comment: But the idea's the same. Instead of using `hist.jpg` you would do something like `"hist.jpg?" + Date.now()`

Comment: `who thinks he is so smart by caching the content, I have enough! I DON'T WANT ANY CACHE!!` Dude Chrome is the mother of all caching. Why blame just one browser, blame all. I think you are not bothered about your pages loading slow for your users.
Besides that point, you can set headers in IIS and Apache to not cache your images (or other static content).

Comment: You are totally right. I am not trying to attach firefox. I am just feel frustrated after so much effort and still can't to get the image reloaded.