# Refresh Image onload with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, caching

I'm working on a wordpress editor where I need to be able to refresh images without having to reload the page. However, I'm not getting the plot as I'm not really a javascript master :(

I'm running this, but in the console log, all I get is: "Uncaught ReferenceError: updateImage is not defined". What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>

    var newImage = new Image();
    newImage.src = "http://2famous.tv/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Dubai-Sky-scrapers_thumb_one.jpg";

    function updateImage() {
    if(newImage.complete) {
        document.getElementById("thumb1").src = newImage.src;
        newImage = new Image();
        newImage.src = "http://2famous.tv/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Dubai-Sky-scrapers_thumb_one.jpg?" + new Date().getTime();

    }

        setTimeout(updateImage, 1000);
    };


</script>

<img id="thumb1" src="image.jpg" onload="updateImage();">
```

Comment: newImage.complete <--- ".complete" is not JavaScript.

Comment: Not sure... have it from this thread: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url

Comment: This code works as written here.  Usually when I get that error there is a javascript syntax error somewhere on the page, usually a close bracket } or something. Do you have other javascript code on the page?

Comment: @Diodeus - yes it is.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FHTMLImageElement

Comment: Wow, never seen that before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When the `<img>` is loading, the `<script>` is not loaded yet. So, the `updateImage()` method doesn't exists. Try to use jquery, there you could do it easily with the *ready* event.

Comment: I think that my best option here is to use unique filenames for each adjustment...