# Display most recent image from folder

Tags: scripting

I want to show the most recent image from a folder (Windows) and have the page (.html) automatically refresh, say, every 5 seconds. What's the easiest way to do this? I prefer not to install any software for this and do it in (for example) the browser.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: You wouldn't. The browser JS doesn't have direct access to the local filesystem. You need something else that feeds the file information to the browser.

Comment: Could you clarify if this needs to be a web-based solution or something that could run interactively on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get the creation date of an image using only JS.
You need to either try an **AJAX solution**, or use a **specific name** for the last saved file 
(f.e: "lastimg.png")

---

For the 5second refresh mechanism You can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval).
Using this solution, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url) topic might also be useful for You. 
*For a more specific answer, try to ask a more specific question.*

Comment: I agree that the question was lacking information. The thing is, I wasn't actually sure whether Javascript was the best way to go. Obviously it's not. I just have a simple task to do, showing the most recent image on a screen, but I'm not sure what the easiest way to do this is.