# backbone or jquery : how clear just one image from cache browser

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, browser-cache

i know this way that extend src of image with ?version=new Date.gettime **but** this way can't help me please tell me how clear one image from brwoser image cache.
also i will not refresh page to any way .
tnx.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refresh image with a new one at the same url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url)

Comment: i know this way but it cant help me.tnx

Comment: If you read through the answers, it exhaustively details many different techniques. See this answer for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22429796/332868 If you believe your question is not a duplicate you should explain why you believe your case is not covered in that question.

Comment: `but it cant help me` ???? explain this..

Comment: i work with backbone and i would chage profile image.i will after successfull upload without render any of views change images that same with profile image.is enough????

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript for a particular image-id like,

```
document.getElementById('image-id').src += new Date().getTime();
```

And in **jquery** try,

```
$('#image-id')[0].src +=  new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: please see my question.this way not usefull for my target

Comment: when you use this way older image remain in cahce browser and i dont want it

Comment: Yes, I read it *tell me how clear one image from brwoser image cache*