# Changing existing image with new one using jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, caching, loading

I am displaying an image on my web page which is present in the web-inf resources folder. When I click a button, a jquery ajax call is made to the server and the image in the web-inf folder is replaced with a new image but the name is same and immediately I want to display the new image instead of old image without reloading the webpage. I could do it by reloading but i don't want because all this is happening in a dialog. If I reload the dialog disappears. In the browser console I could identify that the url of img resource is pointed to new image only but the old image is being displayed. I also tried cache:false in ajax call.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want to append a timestamp to break cache:

```
newImage = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg?" + new Date().getTime();
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kckekq6d/

This was adapted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url). See it for more info.