# How to append timestamp to force refresh of image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append a timestamp to the query string to force a refresh of the images or any other way to force a refresh. It does not seem to refresh my images by setting ajaxSetup cache to false.

How would I do it otherwise?

The jquery for this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({'cache':false});
        $('#right').load('score.html');
     alert('loaded');
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({'cache':false});
        $('#right').load('score.html');
    }, 10000);
    });
</script>
```

The score.html

```
<img class="small" src="VTVFile1.jpg" alt="Image not found" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='demo.jpg';" />
<img class="small" src="VTVFile2.jpg" alt="Image not found" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='demo.jpg';" />

<img class="small" src="VTVFile3.jpg" alt="Image not found" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='demo.jpg';" />
<img class="small" src="VTVFile4.jpg" alt="Image not found" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='demo.jpg';" />
```

Comment: you can add parameter to your get request for image. f.e it describes here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url

Comment: I have looked at that unfortunately not getting it correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
<img class="small" src="VTVFile1.jpg" 
alt="Image not found" 
onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='demo.jpg?'+new Date().getTime();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) function

```
$('#right').load('score.html?r='+Math.random());
```