# The document.getElementById is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
    <img src="generate.php" id="captchaimg"/>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('captchaimg').src='generate.php';">Not readable? Change code.</a>
```

**I know this question is already asked** but the methods described in that is not working for me or i dont know the proper way of using. I have used the code as inline and i created a normal Javascript function and eventhough i checked with the JQuery code on click but the image is not loading in the Firefox whereas the Captcha image is loading correctly on Chrome when i click the Not Readable so please Help me friends to fix the issue Thanks in advance Dude!!!

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: In the example given, the src of the image is the same as the src in the onclick, I am guessing that firefox won't reload the image is the src is the same.

Comment: Do you know that it is `getElementById` that's not working?  It's more likely that FF is seeing the same image `src` being set and not reloading the image.  Try appending a ["cache breaker"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url)

Comment: I tested it. It is working. https://jsfiddle.net/qmnsefqz/

Comment: works fine in FF Version 36.0.1

Comment: Thanks friends... there is no console error and im using the FF version  36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firefox is not loading the content because the source is same.  I just append the date and time to make it as the new source attachment and it got worked
  credits: **cache breaker" –  James Thorpe**, **Salketer**

```
<img src="generate.php" id="captchaimg"/>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('captchaimg').src='generate.php?'+ new Date().getTime();">Not readable? Change code.</a>
```

Comment: this sounds very hackish

Answer (score 2):

I think your example above may not be working because when you refresh the captcha you set the `src` attribute to `generate.php`, which is exactly the same as what it was before. Firefox probably thinks it's not worth re-fetching the image as the same URL is used. To get around this I've set the `src` to nothing, then set it back to `generate.php`.

It's also best practice to take out more complicated Javascript from your HTML elements and move them into their own script. As a basic example, you could try something like this:

```
<img src="generate.php" id="captchaimg" />
<a id="regenerateLink" href="#">Not readable? Change code.</a>

<script>
var captcha = document.getElementById('captchaimg');
var regenerateLink = document.getElementById('regenerateLink');

regenerateLink.onclick = function() {
  captcha.src = "";
  captcha.src = "generate.php";
};
</script>
```

Please note there's still a lot to improve here and I wouldn't consider the code production ready, but it's a start :)