# How to reload updated file in Threepenny-gui 0.6?

Tags: haskell, threepenny-gui

The Threepenny-gui changelog (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.6.0.1/changelog) reads: "The functions loadFile and loadDirectory have been removed, as I felt that the jsStatic option is sufficient for most use cases."

My question is: **how can we reload an image that is updated during execution without loadFile?**

With Threepenny-gui 0.5 I used the following code:

```
redraw :: UI.Element -> IORef CompTree -> (Maybe Vertex) -> UI ()
redraw img treeRef mcv
  = do tree <- UI.liftIO $ readIORef treeRef
       UI.liftIO $ writeFile ".Hoed/debugTree.dot" (shw $ summarize tree mcv)
       UI.liftIO $ system $ "dot -Tpng -Gsize=9,5 -Gdpi=100 .Hoed/debugTree.dot "
                          ++ "> .Hoed/wwwroot/debugTree.png"
       url <- UI.loadFile "image/png" ".Hoed/wwwroot/debugTree.png"
       UI.element img # UI.set UI.src url
```

When, with Threepenny-gui 0.6, I set `jsStatic` to `Just "./.Hoed/wwwroot"`, the following code (obviously) results in my GUI only showing the initial image that already was there when my application started:

```
redraw :: UI.Element -> IORef CompTree -> (Maybe Vertex) -> UI ()
redraw img treeRef mcv
  = do tree <- UI.liftIO $ readIORef treeRef
       UI.liftIO $ writeFile ".Hoed/debugTree.dot" (shw $ summarize tree mcv)
       UI.liftIO $ system $ "dot -Tpng -Gsize=9,5 -Gdpi=100 .Hoed/debugTree.dot "
                          ++ "> .Hoed/wwwroot/debugTree.png"
       UI.element img # UI.set UI.src "static/debugTree.png"
       return ()
```

My full code for Threepenny-gui 0.5 is here: https://github.com/MaartenFaddegon/Hoed/blob/master/Debug/Hoed/DemoGUI.hs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Author here.) Apparently, I didn't consider your use case when removing these functions. :-) I can add them back in if you like, could make an issue on github?

There are various methods on the JavaScript side to reload a file at a certain URL. See for instance the question ["Refresh image with a new one at the same url"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1077041/403805).

Comment: Appending # and a counter that is incremented on each redraw to the image url works for me, so no need to add these functions again. Thanks!