# Why don't browsers respect Cache-Control headers for images loaded with `(new Image()).src = ...`?

Tags: caching, browser-cache

Test case:

```
<script>
console.log('request');
(new Image()).src = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mapbox-gl-js/tests/no-cache.png';

setInterval(function() {
    console.log('request');
    (new Image()).src = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mapbox-gl-js/tests/no-cache.png';
}, 5000);
</script>
```

Neither Chrome nor Firefox make any network requests for `no-cache.png` beyond the first, despite it being served with `Cache-Control: no-cache`, indicating that user agents *must* revalidate cached content.

A few questions here ([e.g. this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url)) touch on this and provide workarounds, but I'm most interested in answering more fundamental questions:

- What web specifications, if any, permit or require this behavior?
- If it is not specified, is it at least officially documented by one or more browsers?
- What controls, if any, do web authors have over this behavior?
- In particular, is there a way to bust the cache without losing the benefits of revalidation via `If-None-Match`, as the use of a cache-busting query parameter does?

Comment: I've filed an [issue in the Chromium tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=530266) asking about this as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The special behavior for images is specified in [the HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#ignore-higher-layer-caching):

> Each `Document` object must have a **list of available images**. Each image in this list is identified by a tuple consisting of an absolute URL, a CORS settings attribute mode, and, if the mode is not No CORS, an origin. Each image furthermore has an **ignore higher-layer caching flag**.

It is this flag that controls whether a user agent removes an entry from the list of available images or not given higher-layer caching semantics for the resource (e.g. the HTTP `Cache-Control` response header).

The flag is *set* and the image added to the list of available images when the networking task to load an image source completes.

According to [this comment](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=530266#c3) on a Chromium bug inquiring about this behavior, `Cache-Control: no-store` will override this behavior in Chrome, but this is subject to change.

Besides `Cache-Control: no-store` or appending a cache-busting query parameter to the URL, which also disables revalidation via `If-None-Match`, I know of one other way of bypassing the ignore higher-level caching flag: load the image data via `XMLHttpRequest`, setting `xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer'`, create a `Blob` object with the response data, and then load the blob into an `Image` with `createObjectURL`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        // ... do something with img
        URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
    };
    var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(xhr.response)], { type: 'image/png' });
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
};
xhr.send();
```