# API Buienradar update every x time

Tags: javascript, api, refresh

In my domotica script i work with an API for "buienradar"
It will load in the page but will not refresh every "x" time. So the API will stay on the loop that is build on the first load in the page.

How can i change my script that the API refresh every hour with new information from the internet / API?

BR,
Jeroen

```
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Buienradar</h3>
            </div><!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="medium-box-body">
                <img id="radarupdate">
                </img>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>




<script>
    $(function() { Domotica.dashboard.init(); });   

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#radarupdate').attr("src","http://api.buienradar.nl/image/1.0/RadarMapNL?w=256&h=256");
        setInterval(function(){
            $('#radarupdate').attr("src","http://api.buienradar.nl/image/1.0/RadarMapNL?w=256&h=256");

            var html = '<img border="0" src="http://api.buienradar.nl/image/1.0/RadarMapNL?w=256&h=256">';
        },900000);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Image Caching**

Browsers tend to ignore cache control and expiry headers on document images. See previous questions "[Why don't browsers respect cache control hearders for images loaded with new Image()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509280/why-dont-browsers-respect-cache-control-headers-for-images-loaded-with-new-im)" and 
 "[Refresh image with a new one at the same URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url)". Sadly the practice is protected in the [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#ignore-higher-layer-caching) with no means of controlling it from script.

In this question radar images on the server are given a cache expiry of 60 seconds after modification, but image content appears static for 5 minutes (?). Here is a sample of the cache expiry header:

```
last-modified Sun, 07 Jan 2018 01:33:46 GMT
expires Sun, 07 Jan 2018 01:34:46 GMT
```

Images are cached in memory and on disk. Reading the response headers for an expired resource invalidates the disk cache, and using a hash component on the URL (starting with "#") invalidates the memory cache. Chrome is happy with just invalidating the disk cache but Firefox requires the hash tag to invalidate its memory cache as well. Using both got the radar image updated in both browsers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var radarURL = "http://api.buienradar.nl/image/1.0/RadarMapNL?w=256&h=256";
    var count = 0;

    function readHeaders(){
        $.ajax( radarURL, {
             method: "HEAD",
             success: updateImage
          }
        );
        setTimeout( readHeaders, (6 - new Date().getMinutes()%5) * 60000); // see note
    }

    function updateImage() {
        count +=1;
        var differentURL = radarURL + "#" + count; // change hash component
        $('#radarupdate').attr("src", differentURL);
    }
    readHeaders();  // first time
});
```

Note

- `readHeaders` sets a timer to call itself between one and two  minutes after the end of the current 5 minute interval in the hour. This could be made more precise by including seconds in the calculation, or altered to update images less frequently.
- If the page is loaded between image update on the server and the end of a 5 minute interval (plus a minute or two), the first update will show the same image. The second update should load a different GIF.
- HTTP requests for the image are made using its published URL without additional query parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction and new script I tested and the frame will not update with new data from the website from buienradar. It seems that he will do a refresh after the time set in the scrip beacause i see still "hanging" picture. But after the time period he "load" again the same data that was running before (launched on the moment from opening the total website)

Comment: Sorry I saw it working in Firefox and posted. Today I could not reproduce the result under conditions suitable for sharing (:.  The new answer was tested in current Chrome and Firefox versions but unfortunately there is still no standard solution.

Comment: Many thanks!
Now it will refresh :)

I only have to check why the forecast time is 20 till 30 minutes instead of one hour that the site will tell me.

But i'm happy with this schript and the result, thanks #traktor53