# How to reload an image using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my **captcha.php** script: *(it creates an image)*

```
// creating a image in this script and set its value on the session
```

Also I have a `<img>` in the **contact_us.php** file for showing that captcha image:

```
<img src="http://localhost/captcha.php" class="captcha_pic" alt="Captcha">
```

Also I have an ajax code for submiting that form in the **contact_us.js** *(this file is atteched to contact_us.php)*:

```
$("#f_contact_form").on("submit", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(e);
   $.ajax({
      url:  $("#f_contact_form").attr("action"),
      type: 'POST',
      data: $("#f_contact_form").serialize(),
      dataType : 'JSON',
      success: function (contact) {
        $(".contact_message").html(contact.message);

        // here I need to reload that image url for changing the captcha image

      }
   });
});
```

It should be noted that when I change the url of that image using *[inspect element]* (in the static) and then I write the correct name, the image will be changed. for example I replace the current image url with `src=".../captcha.ph"` and then I write the correct name `src=".../captcha.php"`, then the page will be changed (exactly what I want).

Now there is any solution for reloading captcha image?

Comment: Try and see if any cache buster works(ex: appending time as query string)

Comment: can't inject image file contents directly into the dom , image must be in `<img>` tag. Look into how to use base64 encoded image url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reload your image with a unique query string attached to it, in order to prevent your browser from caching the image. The easiest way is to just append the current time. [Since you are already using jQuery, here's one way you can do it.](http://jsfiddle.net/ow8u8qxq/)

```
var unique = $.now();
$('.captcha_pic').attr('src', 'http://localhost/captcha.php?' + unique);
```

[However, some people may recommend against this solution as it can fill up your cache.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9943419/4833127) Although the alternative will require that you send cache control headers.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of solution for there. 
Here are some of your options.

1. Remove your images , then create a new one.

   ```
     $("#images").remove();
     $("div").html("<img src='http://localhost/captcha.php' class='captcha_pic' alt='Captcha'>")
   ```
2. Using unique to avoid cache.

   ```
    $("#f_contact_form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
       $.ajax({
          url:  $("#f_contact_form").attr("action"),
          type: 'POST',
          data: $("#f_contact_form").serialize(),
          dataType : 'JSON',
          success: function (contact) {
            $(".contact_message").html(contact.message);
            $('.captcha_pic').attr('src', 'http://localhost/captcha.php?' + new Date().getTime());
          }
       });
    });
   ```

Comment: Thanks. +1 upvote fore you. However your first solution does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

$.now() [has been deprecated in jQuery 3.3](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.now/).
Correct way based on accepted answer:

```
var unique = Date.now();
$('.captcha_pic').attr('src', 'http://localhost/captcha.php?' + unique);
```