# Second image is not displayed correctly when first image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, random

***Functionality:***

When user clicks on a first image, the second image will fade in and be displayed. The second image is a child of the first image. Therefore, the second image shown has to be connected with the first image.

For e.g: there are 4 images and they are grouped in an array. 
for first image`var firstImage= ["image1", "image2", "image3", "image4"]`
for second image`var secondImage= ["image1a", "image2a", "image3a", "image4a"]`

therefore, when I click on "image1", the corresponding image that will fade in will be "image1a"

***What I have done:***

As stated above:

1.) I have grouped the 2 different images into an array
2.) I have randomised the first array of images and it is displayed in the list in a randomised manner.
3.) I have tried to append the second image to the first image when clicked.

This is my code:

```js
var slideDuration = 1200;
var idleTime = 0;
var BrandNameArray = ["http://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/paris,girl/all?", "http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg", "http://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/paris,girl/all?", "http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg"];

var OfferArray = ["http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg", "http://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/paris,girl/all?", "http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg", "http://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/paris,girl/all?"];



$(function() {

  //Auto populate into brand container once randomised for each Brand image
  var BrandNameArrayBackup = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(BrandNameArray));
  for (i = 0; i < $('#list').find('img').length; i++) {
    //To Set random Brand
    var random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);
    //Assign Variable to generate random Brands
    var Brand = BrandNameArray[random_BrandIndex];
    BrandNameArray.splice(random_BrandIndex, 1);
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).attr('src', Brand);
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).show();
    console.log(Brand);
  }
  BrandNameArray = BrandNameArrayBackup; //re-assigning values back to array
});

function selectBrand(index) {

  $('#Vivo_BrandDescription').fadeIn({
    duration: slideDuration,
    queue: false
  });

  var chosenBrandIndex = OfferArray[index];
  //Set option clicked to CSS change 
  $('#Description').attr('src', chosenBrandIndex);
  $('#Description').show();
}

function Vivo_BrandDescription() {
  idleTime = 0;

  $("#border_page").fadeOut(function() {
    $("#Vivo_BrandDescription").fadeIn();
  });
}
```

```css
.Container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 1260px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.innerScroll {
  position: relative;
  width: 1250px;
  height: 600px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #8d8989 !important;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="ChooseBrand" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; background-repeat: no-repeat;z-index=3; top:0px; left:0px;">

  <div class="Container">
    <div id="list" class="innerScroll">
      <!--1st Row-->
      <img id="Brand_1" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:0px; border:0px; outline:0px" data-brand="1">
      <img id="Brand_2" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:330px; border:0px;" data-brand="2">
      <img id="Brand_3" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:650px; border:0px;" data-brand="3">
      <img id="Brand_4" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:965px; border:0px;" data-brand="4">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="BrandDescription" class="menu" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display:none; top:0px; left:0px; z-index=10;">

    <img id="Description" style="position:absolute; top:124px; left:534px;z-index=11;">
  </div>
```

***Issue:***

At this point in time, is that when I click on a random image, the corresponding image is not correctly displayed.

For example, when I clicked on "image1", the resulting image that faded in is displaying "image4a" instead of "image1a". All first array images have been randomised.

Hence, what have I done incorrectly or not done. Please help, thanks.

Comment: It's a little difficult to fully understand your issue (at least to me). Also it seems code is not complete (maybe?). Anyway, first thing first, try to take it down to the barebones logics, excluding as much computation (js) and presentation (html, css/fx/positioning) as you can, if possible. And use logs, not elements, again when possible. This way you and us can better focalize the real issue. Also, this way we're more sure it's not for ex. a mere css problem or the like.

Comment: @Stratboy, which part do you have difficulty in? I would like to try my best to explain the issue fully.

Comment: Then start with what I wrote above ;)

Comment: check this out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275269/image-is-not-displayed-when-parent-image-is-clicked/36284374