# web2py: Reload component with an image (in same location/URL) by another component

Tags: web2py

My problem is, that I need to reload a component which is containing an image by another component. The image is generated by a function/controller and has thus always the same location/URL.

The reload triggered by the second component reloads the first component but doesn't update the image loaded within the first component

Thus, my question is:
How can I update/reload the image loaded by the first component?

Thanks for any support!

Regards
Clemens

Comment: Maybe the argument which is passed by the initial load is the problem. Doing some search on the web, I found a solution using web2py_component. But there I get the message 'insufficient privileges' and 'access denied'. Both components use 'user_signature=True' or at least component_1 ... no difference.

Comment: I've added an JS-alert to response.js - the alert is shown. But not the update/reload of component_1. As further information: component_1 has a div containing a dynamically create graph very similar to the bg_graph_model() in appadmin.py. Is this the problem, that component_1 is using a further controller/function?

Comment: The problem is obviously that the image (generated) is not updated/reloaded when the component is reloaded. Thus, the question could be how to reload an image which is part of a component, since the change of that image is the reason to reload.

Comment: Maybe ask on the web2py google group if you get no help here.

Comment: Thanks Terrence. I will follow your advice, if I don't find a solution. But I think, I know the problem. It seems not to be a web2py problem but a jQuery problem. Obviously jQuery is not updating the image as long as it has the same name. Since I'm generating the image by a function call, this is the case. Today I'm gonna evaluate this. If this is the solution I will write it down here. If not, I will switch to the web2py google group ... so thanks again for that tip, Terrence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not a web2py one but a jQuery one. As long as the URL of the image to be reloaded/updated is the same (due to image is generated or updated in place). The solution is to add a dynamically generated extension to the URL e.g. as vars to the image call and to be dropped by the generation:

```
response.js =  'jQuery("#graph_img").attr("src","%s?"+Date.now());' % URL('default', 'generate_graph', args=['browser','1'])
```

I came to this solution by the following Stack Overflow post:
[Refresh image with a new one at the same url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url)