# Cross-browser issue, CSS not loaded

Tags: css

I am experiencing that some of my CSS rules are being ignored by Firefox, IE and Safari, while it looks right in Chrome, which I have developed for. 
I have hard refreshed, cleared the browser cache, used computers that never visited the site before and browsershots. Furthermore, I cleared CSS and JS in the cache management. Checking the CSS files I can see that the browsers are refering to old versions of the CSS files that does not match what I uploaded to the server. Why are the browsers loading old CSS versions?
My website is: http://www.thirstforgreat.com/merchandise.html

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The browsers cached and were still using the old CSS files. You will have to let the browsers know that they need to download a new file.

One option is to change the URL query parameters for your CSS files to force browsers to get a different copy for each file version. You can use the file version identifier:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/css.php?version=1.2" type="text/css" />
```

For other options, see the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url).

If you go with appending the file version as query parameter to the CSS files, you will notice that your browser does not reload the file when you're still testing modifications to the same file version. In this case, you can [force your browser to do a hard refresh](https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers/).