# Updating asp.net JPG File

Tags: c#, python, asp.net

So: Im searching for Hours now, but i cant find anything:

Im trying to do an Application for my moving Robo Lamp(Tracking your face and trying to look towards you)

And its made in ASP.net, The Facetracking is in Python.

What im doing right now:
ive got an Page, called Cam1. My Python Programm saves Frames as .jpg files, and ASP.net gets this image

```
@{
string pythonworkingdic = "C:/Users/HurricanKai/AnacondaProjects/GaDOSlamp/";
var imagePath = "Views/Python/tmp.jpg";
}
```

my html is just an:

```
<img src=@imagePath alt="Cam1 View" />
```

i dont think i have to paste the python code here, im jus tusing cv2

so what my actual Problem is:
i want to update the picture all the time, but to get an new Image i always need to reload the page...

Thanks already :)

Comment: What page? This doesn't seem like a question that can be answered, this is a pretty involved problem.

Comment: just an ASP.NET page, empty, no model created in it just the code uper

Comment: You're looking for Javascript.

Comment: Jeah, i have no idea of javascript....

Comment: You need to make calls with ajax, and update it dynamically

Comment: @Tomas Smagurauskas ok, looks like an idea, coud you give me an example, or an resource?

Comment: Look what I found on Stack Overflow: [Refresh image with a new one at the same url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to refresh the page manually, you can add the following meta tag to your  tag that will refresh it automatically.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

The above meta tag will refresh the page every 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks :D im using this for now.

Comment: If this is a suitable solution for what you want to do, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I know, but it isnt what i was realy looking for, ill mark it anyways ...