# NodeJS sending an image(which may be modified) to the client with middleware

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I want to mention that the image file is changing continuously.
I'm using the middleware of NodeJS:

```
app.use("/image.jpg",express.static(_dirname+"/image.jpg")
```

The problem is that the Node conveys the image.jpg without really telling that the file has been modified.
Pressing a button this part will occur.

```
var image=new Image();
image.onload=function(){rendering to canvas}
image.src="/image.jpg";
```

Somehow there is a problem...

The server's picture file gets modified then it emits to the client to draw the image, regarding to the results, the client is rendering the first image it has loaded again, although the image on the url has been changed.
I think the client is caching the image? and thinks that the image is unmodified so it keeps using it.
Is there a way to draw the current image on the url? 
Are there even better methods?

Comment: Does the filename change, or just the image data?

Comment: I think the client is caching the image and preventing a new http request.

Comment: just the image data changes @PatrickRoberts

Comment: If you want the client to update the image in realtime, I have an answer that involves socket.io. If you're okay with using socket.io, I'll go ahead and write the answer.

Comment: Here, a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url

Comment: Merci @JoseHermosillaRodrigo I think this will work

Comment: You're welcome! Also @PatrickRoberts is right, you'll need something to do a realtime comunication between client and server for the client to know wheter the image data has changed, but with the provided information I suspect you're done with this, since you say `The server's picture file gets modified then it emits to the client`

Comment: Looks disrespecting from me, I didn't see his comment, :') I'm using socket.io for emiting

Comment: So then you've already implemented `fs.watch()` as well?

Comment: I tried to use the middleware again app.use(...) to solve the cache problem, but since it didn't work, I didn't use the fs.watch(); , I think I will use this for streaming...for now the user is pressing a button..

Comment: @OnlyMyRailgun see my answer for what I had in mind when I mentioned `fs.watch()` and `socket.io`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`fetch()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to implement [cache-busting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache) without cluttering your client's browser cache with a bunch of `/image.jpg?bust=...` resources.

After deciding on a folder in your server that you want to allow static access to changing files (this is preferable to the pattern where you allowed static access to a single file), you can implement your real-time updates using [`fs.watch()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) like so:

Node `app.js` ([with express 3/4](https://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4)):

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const app = require('express')()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080)

app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './watched-directory')))

//...

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  //...
});

fs.watch('watched-directory', {
  //don't want watch process hanging if server is closed
  persistent: false,
  //supported on Windows OS / Mac OSX
  recursive: true,
}, (eventType, filename) => {
  if (eventType === 'change') {
    io.emit('filechange', filename)
  }
})
```

Browser `index.html`:

```html
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  let socket = io.connect()

  socket.on('filechange', async (filename) => {
    console.log(filename)

    let response = await fetch(filename, { cache: 'no-store' })
    let blob = await response.toBlob()
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

    //modified from your question
    let image = new Image()
    image.addEventListener('load', () => {
      //your canvas rendering code here
    })
    image.src = url
  })
</script>
```

Comment: ()=> = function(), let, await, async  are new for me .-. I will study your code!

Comment: @OnlyMyRailgun At least in this case, [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is effectively the same thing as `var`, but for the others, [`() => {}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), is just syntactic sugar in ES2017 for dealing with [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), which the `fetch()` API uses.