# How to refresh images each specific time ? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, html, widget

I have a simple HTML page with

```
<img src="http://www.hamqsl.com/solar101pic.php">
```

And this image get an update every day

How can I make my page update this image every day or every 12 hours

The reason I want JavaScript to update it 
Cuz I use it in an HTML widget 
Which doesn't update it self

Comment: Does page refresh also not update the image?

Comment: @Max08 If i refresh the page in a browser the image get updated

Comment: @Max08 but as a widget I don't have an option of clicking refresh

Comment: Your server should be setting the correct caching headers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> `setInterval(function() {
>     location.reload();
>   }, 5000);`

**Update**

i think your logic wont do the trick because the browser start the count when u open it so the image will change after 12 hours from opening it not at specific time so you have to options

1. Set the Image Url On server Side
2. assign an image to each hour on a clock

Comment: yeah thats true im changing it now

Comment: OP wants to refresh an image, and 3 out of 4 solutions given here suggest to reload the whole page. Downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

As explained on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url), just use a cache breaker to reload your image :

```js
const img = document.getElementById("myImage")

setInterval( () => {
   img.src = "http://www.hamqsl.com/solar101pic.php?" + new Date().getTime();
}, 1000*3600*12) // 12 hours in ms
```

```html
<img id="myImage" src="http://www.hamqsl.com/solar101pic.php" />
```

By adding `?randomstuff` after the URL, you force the browser to fetch a fresh copy of the file because it's not identified as being in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to manually update the link for the image?  Or does the "101" in the URL increment?

If the link is static, except for some kind of numeric integer, then I would use JavaScript to inject HTML onto your web page.  Check:

```
var imgHtml = '<img src="http://www.hamqsl.com/solar101pic.php">';
document.getElementById('tag-id').innerHTML = imgHtml
```

You can use the Date.now() function to get the epoch time, and then play with MOD(%) to set a proper interval.  This is how you get 12 hours.  I'll leave it to you to find out.

Comment: The image get updated by the server of the website

Answer (score -1):

`window.location.reload(true)` forces page reload without using the cached version. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload))

You can implement a timer this way:

```
setTimeout(function(){  
  window.location.reload(true);
},4.32e+7); // 12 hours refresh rate. This is the time, in milliseconds.
```

More info on [`setTimeout` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).

Comment: OP wants to refresh an image, and 3 out of 4 solutions given here suggest to reload the whole page. Downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

You can use either Javascript's setTimeout function which will fire the event once it hits the specified timer (in milliseconds):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload(1);
}, 3600);
```

Or you can use the following meta tag (in seconds):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600" />
```

EDIT: Just thought of a better way. How about deleting the element using jQuery and then redrawing the element again?

Comment: It's fairly poor UX to force a user to refresh their page. I wouldn't recommend either of these two solutions.

Comment: @Richie We're answering what the OP asks for. He's not asking for UX-elegant solutions, he's asking for us to refresh his page.

Comment: @JeffNoel he's not asking how to refresh his page, he is asking how to update an image. There are less obtrusive ways to do it.

Comment: OP wants to refresh an image, and 3 out of 4 solutions given here suggest to reload the whole page. Downvoted.