# Image source not changing with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image

Please answer this question, as I am struggling a lot with it.

I am trying to change image source on mouse over. I am able to do it, but image is not displaying on page.

I am trying to change image source to cross domain URL. I can see that in DOM image source is changing but on page its not.

I have tried all solutions mentioned in [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url), but none of them is working.
Please let me solution to problem.
**NOTE:**

1. I can see in network tab image is taking some time to download (about 1 sec).
2. It is an intermediate issue, sometime image is loading and sometimes its not

**CODE:**

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].addEventListener('mouseover', function() 
{
    document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].setAttribute('src', 'url/of/the/image');
});
```

Comment: please put some code to help you

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón added. there is no issue with code. I am struggling with changing image source with cross domain URL

Comment: Best guess is leech protection. Surely you have tested that the image works if you put it on the page as an <img> tag without JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, that image is loading without javascript.

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: No, @lumio.. its an intermediate issue, sometime image is loading and sometimes its not

Comment: How about removing the whole `img` tag and replacing it with a new one?

Comment: Yes @KaranDhir I can do that.. Please help me with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue using code:

```
function displayImage() {
    let image = new image();
    image.src="source/of/image/returned/from/service";
    image.addEventListener('load', function () { 
        document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = image.src;
    },false);
}
```

Here in code, I am attaching load event to image, source of image will be changed after image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried loading images before everything else?

```
function initImages(){
    var imC = 0;
    var imN = 0;
    for ( var i in Images ) imN++;
    for(var i in Images){
        var t=Images[i];
        Images[i]=new Image();
        Images[i].src=t;
        Images[i].onload = function (){ 
            imC++; 
            if(imC == imN){
                console.log("Load Completed");
                preloaded = 1;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
var Images = {
    one image: "path/to/1.png",
    ....
}
```

then

```
if( preloaded == 1 ){
    start_your_page();
}
```

Comment: I am getting images from service call, and this call is on mouseover.. So at time of page load I dont know the set of images that I have.

Answer (score 0):

Here the code that will remove the `img` tag and replace it with a new one:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].parentElement;
  parent.removeChild(document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]);
  var new_img = document.createElement("img");
  new_img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/600x400_kastra.jpg";
  parent.appendChild(new_img);
});
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg">
```

Comment: Using this approach, on creating new img tag then we need to add mouseout event to new image tag created, which is again a challenge.

Comment: Why do you need to have a mouseout event?

Comment: On mouseout I want to restore original image.

Comment: Yes indeed! Do you want me to write the code for that too?

Comment: I have atleast 100 + images on page and this approach doesn't seems correct to me. And will introduce more issues/bugs in code.