# CORS on canvas not working on Chrome and Safari

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, amazon-s3, safari, cors

I'm trying to display images on a canvas. The images are hosted on S3.

CORS is set up on AWS, and the `CrossOrigin` attribute is set to `anonymous` in the script.

**Everything works fine on Firefox** — but images are not being loaded on Chrome and Safari.

*Errors Safari:*

> Origin https://www.example.com is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
>   http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/bubble/foo.PNG
>
> [Error] Failed to load resource: Origin https://www.example.com is not
>   allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (foo.PNG, line 0)
>
> Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing
>   policy.

*Errors Chrome:*

> Access to Image at 'https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/bubble/foo.PNG'
>   from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

The CORS configuration is pretty standard. I tried `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>`, and a couple of other variations, but it didn't make any difference … with one exception: `<AllowedOrigin>null</AllowedOrigin>` seemed to work for Chrome.

**CORS configuration on AWS**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://www.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://www.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

**Canvas Script**

```
let myImage = new Image();
myImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

myImage.src = thisDocument.url;
myImage.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvas.setAttribute('width', 200);
  canvas.setAttribute('height', 200);

  context.fillStyle = hsl(0, 50%, 50%);
  context.fillRect(0, 0, 120, 120);
  context.drawImage(myImage, 12, 12, 60, 60);
};
```

Comment: `origin 'null'` != `http[s]://example.com` from your allowed origins.  I'm guessing `origin 'null'` means you're testing as `http://localhost`?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case. :( The app runs on Meteor's Galaxy (Docker/AWS), and the images are hosted on S3.

Comment: What is the solution to this? Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60024200/chrome-v76-cors-problem-amazon-s3-bucket-and-heroku-django-web-app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a very similar issue to this (using S3 hosting with Access-Control errors on Safari and Chrome).

It ended up being a caching issue specific to Chrome and Safari. If you load an image via CSS or an `<img>` tag, the image will be cached without the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

You can check if this is the case for you by disabling caching and checking if the error persists. If it is the issue this answer will likely help: [Refresh image with a new one at the same url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url/22429796#22429796)

Comment: It looks like you're right. The image had been loading, when the developer window was open, and cache was (inadvertently) disabled.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I want to use cache in my site,
How we can cache the image with the access-control-allow-origin header? 
can you please provide some explanation?

Comment: I thought I was going mad until I found this answer - the same image is used in in img tag on my page. I fixed this by adding `?canvas=true` to the url using in my javascript, then it is treated as a separate image.