# Images in stored in AWS S3 not loading in Chrome but work in Firefox

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am hosting static files for a `Django` web application in `AWS` `S3` using the `Python` `storages` package.

The application's static assets load in `Firefox`, but in `Chrome`, the image files will not load. I am running the local `Django` development server.

The error I am getting for the image file is:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/svg/parts/part1.svg' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

My `cors` configuration for the `AWS` bucket is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I am only having issues with the image files. `JavaScript`, `CSS`, and `webfont` files (Fontawesome) are all loading fine in `Chrome`, it's just `.svg` and `.png` files that aren't loading and that I am getting the error for.

All of this works fine in `Firefox` with all images loading from `AWS` `S3`. I have tried the following settings in Django:

```
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = True
```

```
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False
```

I have verified the the URLs in the browser are rendering as either `http` or `https` depending on the boolean value. Neither of these settings makes a difference in `Chrome`.

I am using the `corsheaders` package in `Django` and have the following set in `settings.py`:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

This appears to be a known issue with `Chromium` and `WebKit` browsers, but there isn't much information beyond what I have already tried to get this to work.

I would appreciate and suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350432/cors-on-canvas-not-working-on-chrome-and-safari

Comment: Hey! could you solve this? how did you do?