# How can I refresh a particular row on a flatlist in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to refresh a particular cell/row in a flatlist. How can i just refresh a single cell when data is loaded. And after refreshing display the data?

Is it possible to refresh a particular row in a view of react-native? For e.g i'm displaying images in a row nested inside `<View/>`.

Comment: It would help us a lot if you can show us code you currently have. It's also possible that this questions is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url

Answer (score 2):

You can try `extraData` in `FlatList` to update a particular item in flatlist.
When state is changed the flatlist will rerender.

```
<FlatList

    extraData={this.state}
    data={this.state.asPerCode}
    renderItem={this.renderPost}

/>
```

you can check about extra data in react native flatlist docs.


Hope it helps!

Comment: This will help to referesh the flatlist content whenever there is change in array.

Comment: Is there any way to refresh a single row(say an image styled in row inside a view) inside a view?

Comment: you simply want to update image inside view or image inside view which itself is inside the flatlist's row?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be looking for [React.PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) which implements a shallow prop and state comparison to decide if rerender is needed. You can achieve this with [shouldComponentUpdate() on React.Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) too.

There is already an [example in FlatList's docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) that demonstrate how you can use PureComponent to render your list, just scroll down abit and look for the "more complex example" :)

If you prefer to use a `Functional Component` instead of a `Class Component`, checkout [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), which is similar to `React.PureComponent` but for `Functional Components`. Hope it helps.