# a function that adds a random image shows the same image everytime

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function that creates an image and the src is a random image from splash, but every time i call the function it generates the same image, why and how to fix it

```
function randomImage(){
    const img = document.createElement('img')
    img.src = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x500'
    document.body.appendChild(img)
}
```

As far as i understand each function call is dependent from each other so why each function call in this example generates the same image despite the link itself should generate a random link

Comment: you aren't doing anything to force a refresh. consider adding some entropy to the query string

Comment: That end point seems to return the same image for a bit before it returns a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not generate a random link. You depend on the `source.unsplash.com` to return a random image.

But since your browser page has seen that url, it loads it from the cache.

You could add something random, to make the browser think it is a different url.

```
img.src = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x500&timestamp=' + Date.now()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a cache breaker to your URL, since the browser caches your request and returns the same image.

```js
img.src = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x500?t=' + new Date().getTime()
```

See also: [Refresh image with a new one at the same url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url)

Comment: Thank you so much, that works

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept the answer then. :)