# Refresh image on button click

Tags: javascript, onclick, refresh

I am a self-taught beginner programmer and I'm working on a personal project. I'm having trouble making my code work.

Essentially, I would like to have a button which, when clicked, refreshes the image element on my page. For the image, I use a {placekitten} link.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <button id="kitten-reload">Reload kitten</button>
      <div class="image-container">
        <img
          id="kitten-image"
          src="http://placekitten.com/300/300"
          alt="Cute kittens"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

And here is my JS:

```
const reloadBtn = document.querySelector("#kitten-reload");
const kittenImage = document.querySelector("#kitten-image");
const kittenURL = "http://placekitten.com/300/300";

reloadBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  kittenImage.removeAttribute("src", "");
  kittenImage.setAttribute("src", kittenURL);
});
```

I thought that removing the src attribute and adding a new one afterwards would work, but the image does not change.

What I tried before this:

- creating a function to add a dummy timestamp string at the end of the link (it only worked on the first click)
- trying .load() on the image element (that also involved some JQuery which I'm not familiar with so maybe I messed it up)

I appreciate any suggestions, thank you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refresh image with a new one at the same url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url)