# django media files only available after reloading page (DAPHNE, Debug = True)

Tags: django, media, daphne

1. I have a view that save an image in my media file (im.save('media/test.png')
2. In my template, I try to display it (img src="/media/test.png")

The image will only appear after I reload the page
How can I display the image whitout reloading the page please ?

Comment: After saving, did you get actual url using ajax or something ? Because at saving, django may creat different file name, different one to uploaded file name.

Comment: @Pycm I have a javascript function that add the following code to the page : < img src="/media/test.png" > . It's exactly the same file name (the image appear if I test the same path of the image after I refresh the page)

Comment: Maybe there is some error. It's best if you can post the code.

Answer (score 0):

I see your code and image path perfectly. but implement some extra functionality.

You need to add **JavaScript**, when you upload a new image that time without page reloading you see your uploaded image.

**HTML**

```
<img id="badge" src="$cms_url/imaging/badge.php?badge=$mygroup['badge']; ?>">/imaging/badge.php?badge=<?php echo $mygroup['badge']; ?>" />
document.getElementById("badge").src="new image src here";
```

**Js query**

```
 $("#badge").attr("src", "new image src here");
```

[for more information  Click on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url)