# Internet Explorer 9 does not update with changes on server from my flex application

Tags: apache-flex, internet-explorer, flex4

I have a flex application that when i update on the server i can see the changes in both firefox and and chrome but I.E continues to show the application before the change... Its as if I.E had the application Cashed somewhere. I dont understand where it could be holding it. I have tried clearing my cookies and i still get the same view before my changes. Has anyone else had this problem before with Internet Explorer? Can someone please advice me of what you did to resolve? Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Im very frustuated with this particular problem.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to clear out your Internet explorer cache? A cache is  different from cookies and clearing cookies will not affect your cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wan tot give you one information that IE9 is having a problem with its cache..
You need to clear the cache before executing the FLEX application. In short you need to clear the cache.
Remember that History and Cache are different so delete history and than delete cache.

You can clear the cache by following ways.

1. Press F12
2. New window opens and then press ctrl + r.
3. Alert will appear where u need to click on the Yes button to clear the cache.

Have a Nice Day...

Answer (score 0):

IE sometimes caches, I have in the past used something like this for force the cache. Add a random string to the end of the URL like this:

```
Math.random() * Date.parse(new Date());
```

If building a URL via AJAX call;

```
var url = "somepath/somefile?someparam="+ somevar + "&RandomKey=" +Math.random() * Date.parse(new Date());
```

The RandomKey var is always different, forcing the browser to not cache.

This solution/question is like this one, [JavaScript: how to force Image() not to use the browser cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165253/javascript-how-to-force-image-not-to-use-browser-cache)

Comment: sorry i know this sounds like a stupid question but im not building an url how can i still use this? thanks a million.

Comment: Go to Tools\Internet Options, then click on the Settings button in Browsing History, then select the Every time I visit the webpage radio button. this seemed to work for me.

Answer (score -2):

on IE 9, go to

1. Go to "Internet Options"
2. Under "Browsing History", Click on "Settings"
3. On the pop window click on the button "View files". This will open Windows Explorer
4. Remove all the content in this folder

Comment: This will clear IE's history. You can clean the cache without removing all browser history.